# Align text vertically next to image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align all my text and images centrally vertically. How do I do this? So basically `Hello` appears in the middle of each image & the first image is centered vertically.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ueqba2zf/

```css
div {
    width:75px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background:#eee
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25"> Hello</div>
    
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/25x100"> Hello</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ueqba2zf/

Comment: Can we assume that we know the height of the img beforehand?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Resolved :-D http://jsfiddle.net/ueqba2zf/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea, though its not the best. Unless you have a reasonable way to anticipate the image sizes, it might not be practical. However, I think that without that knowledge or a consistent wrapper around your objects, this won't be possible.

HTML

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img class="small-img" src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
    <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img class="large-img" src="http://placehold.it/25x100" />
    <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-wrap img {
    float: left;
}
.img-wrap img + .text {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 1em;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.small-img + .text {
    transform: translateY(12.5px);
}
.large-img + .text {
    transform: translateY(50px);
}
```

**Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueqba2zf/5/)**

Basically all I'm doing is restricting the text 2 a single line so that its height is predictable and then translating it to be centered relative to the height of the previous image.

If you want more than a single line of text, you could do something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="box small-box">
    <img class="small-img" src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
    <span class="text">Hello There</span>
</div>
<div class="box large-box">
    <img class="large-img" src="http://placehold.it/25x100" />
    <span class="text">Hello There</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.small-box {
    height: 25px;
}
.large-box {
    height: 100px;
}
.box img + .text {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2.2em;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box .small-img + .text {
    left: 25px;
    transform: none;
}
.box .large-img + .text {
    left: 25px;
    transform: none;
}
```

Here I'm actually using absolute position with auto margins to center the text. You need to size the wrapper correctly and limit the amount of visible text but its not bad. Also, consider using a tool like jQuery ellipsis to handle the text overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't done HTML for a while now but something like this should work:

```
<div style="display=block;float:left"><img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" style="height=80px"> <p style:"text-align: center;;width 75px;">Hello</p></div>
```

you can have a look at this:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp